# What happen if assign constant value to int pointer?

Tags: c

If I have assign constant value to **int** pointer then what is happened internally?

Like,  `int *p = 5;`

Then what is a value if I have print ***p** and **p** and Why?

Comment: Nasal Demons (tm) pretty much sums it up.

Comment: What did you already read and which part you did not understand?

Comment: Please show your research effort till time. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: When you tell your computer to display or use the memory contents at address `5` (well within the system reserved area of memory) any number of things can happen. Anything from weird `buss error` error messages to `Segmentation Fault`. Just think about where in memory you are attempting to access and what lives there. If the answer isn't *my program stack* or *the memory I just allocated*, then you are in the wrong place...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have

```
int *p = 5;
```

you have a variable `p` that is pointing to the address `5`. There will most likely not be a valid `int` value at that address. Dereferencing the pointer will most likely lead to *undefined behavior*. Writing to the memory will most likely cause a crash, and as it is unaligned reading it might cause a crash too on some systems that don't allow unaligned reads.

Doing like that *is* valid in some situations, which is why it's allowed. Think for example small embedded systems with a fixed memory map, where certain "registers" are stored at some fixed address. Then you can make a pointer and make it point directly at that address.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
int *p = 5;
```

means that you create a *pointer to an integer* and you assign the value `5` to its content. In other words, you make pointer `p` point to the memory address `5`, where you do not know if there will exist a valid integer value.

- If you print `*p`,  you actually print the ***content of the pointer***, or in other words the value of the integer where `p` points to.

  - If you print `p`,  you actually print the ***address*** of pointer `p`, in other words the memory address where `p` is stored.